# With EF Code First, How to include nested nested data

Tags: entity-framework, code-first

I have three entities as defined below. In my seed method I trivially add one record to each class which leads to a speaker that has a session that has a tenant.

When I materialize speaker data with this:

```
 List<Speaker> speakers = db.Speakers.Include("Sessions").ToList();
```

I get the Session data but I also want the Tenant to be populated in the Session records (which are part of the Speaker records).

I can't figure out the syntax to get speakers that have sessions that have a tenant record.

I'm not sure if this is related but I serialize my "speakers" and when I unserialize it I'm missing the tenant.

```
public DbSet<Tenant> Tenants { get; set; }
public DbSet<Speaker> Speakers { get; set; }
public DbSet<Session> Sessions { get; set; }

[Serializable]
public class Tenant
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class Speaker
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Session> Sessions { get; set; } 
}

[Serializable]
public class Session
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Tenant Tenant { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Speaker> Speakers { get; set; } 

}
```

*** answer:

```
List<Speaker> speakersAll1 =_context.
                            Speakers.
                            Include(a => a.Sessions.Select(b => b.Tenant)).
                            ToList();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to `Include` both your values, like this:

```
 List<Speaker> speakers = db.Speakers.Include("Sessions.Tenant").ToList();
```

This will include the `Tenant` from your `Session` objects as well as your original `Session` objects.

From the [ObjectQuery.Include documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738708(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Paths are all-inclusive. For example, if an include call indicates Include("Orders.OrderLines"), not only will OrderLines be included, but also Orders.

You could also add `using System.Data.Entity;` to use `Include` with a lambda expression so you don't have to rely on magic strings.

Comment: Thanks, I updated by question to include what worked for me.  I included Session first, though I'm guessing that is not necessary.  I'll mark as answer when I can.

Comment: @PeterKellner I see you used the `System.Data.Entity`, that's usually better than relying on magic strings. Hope I could be of some assistance. Also: if you actually ended up using that other method to solve it, you should post it as an answer.